# AWS free tier :EC2 +RDS parellel

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

i am experimenting AWS and would like to deploy a spring boot app on EC2(Linux) and connecting to mysql db instance created with RDS .
as per the reference [AWS freetier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/)

i have query for the scenario, to stay in free tier slab,

- ec2 instance + RDS mysql instance running time >=750 hours  or
- Each ec2 instance instance running time >=750 hours and RDS mysql instance
  running time >=750 hours(parllely running both rds instance and ec2 instance for 750hours/month)

thanks for the support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage limits of each service are **independent**.

Within the first 12 months of an AWS account, you would receive:

- 750 hours per month of Linux, RHEL, or SLES t2.micro instance usage
- 750 Hours per month of db.t2.micro database usage (applicable DB engines)
- etc, all as 'AND' (not 'OR')

Comment: 750 hours per month of Linux, RHEL, or SLES t2.micro instance usage 'AND ' 750 Hours per month of db.t2.micro database usage (applicable DB engines) running parallel= $0 billing/free tier?

Comment: Each service in the AWS Free Usage Tier is independent. You will not be charged for the first _N_ hours of usage that is within the free usage tier. So, if you stay under those amounts, there will be no charge for those services (typically in the first 12 months of the AWS account).